# how to add authentication in swagger user role based

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have a requirement where I want to show list the api methods in swagger-ui based on user roles. i am using spring boot with java 7.

For example :

Some user with basic access can use limited api methods;

Admin can use all the listed api methods;

Comment: It's been 2 years since you've posted this question. By any chance, have you find a way to achieve this?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [list the api in swagger based on user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904213/list-the-api-in-swagger-based-on-user-roles/63246343) You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63246343/6465520)